# General purpose C++ library, without exceptions and RTTI

Tags: c++

Can any of you recommend a general purpose C++ library which is designed to work without exceptions and RTTI.

I expect the library to contain much of the same functionality which exists in the standard library, and are especially interested in containers, algorithms and streams.

I do know that both boost and the standard library have facilities to make them compile without exceptions, but they are not designed to work well in such environment. I believe that both libraries will assert instead of throwing exceptions.

The library should be working on Linux, and be portable to any posix platform.

Comment: No one can recommend a library without knowing your requirements. Do you have some sort of embedded system constraints? If not, why use C++ to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes this is for embedded systems, the library is needed to work under Linux and under eCos. eCos do not have proper support for exceptions if multiple threads are used. And besides, we do not want to introduce exceptions and RTTI in our current software stack.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library implementation should also work well without RTTI and exception support. I can at least confirm that the GCC 4.x implementation does.

Comment: Yes, but if you are using the standard library without exceptions, the container libraries have no good way of informing on errors dues to memory exhaustion. I'm looking for a library which is designed to work well without exceptions.

Comment: Couldn't you roll an allocator of your own (to be used in STL containers), which you can query the status of after an insert operation ?

Comment: In our situation we have this boiling down to the glibc memory management port, that will in fact cause a processor exception when the available heap is exhausted. But this depends on OS and µC used.

Answer (score 2):

If your implementation of the standard library does not work without RTTI or exceptions, get a different implementation.

Otherwise, QtCore implements pretty much everything in the standard library in their own way, along with a bunch of other stuff not available in the C++03/C++11 standard libraries.

Comment: Are you saying that QtCore can be compiled with -fno-exceptions?

Comment: The standard library use RTTI and exceptions because the standards define when and how they must be used in the implementations. Whatever implementation that doesn't use them is not a "standard library" ... but at most a "substandard".

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Both libc++ (LLVM/Clang) and libstdc++ (GCC) can be used without RTTI and exceptions. I'm not sure about MSVC, but I would guess it can do the same. Turning these two features off makes your code/program "nonstandard" anyway. But that is the question.

Comment: @Allan I know Qt can be compiled with the options to disable rtti and exceptions at configure time. I was also pretty sure that the Qt API does not throw exceptions outside library boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [uCLibc++](http://cxx.uclibc.org/index.html) is an alternative, at least amongst its features is lack of exceptions/RTTI.

Edit: Sorry it seems that [Embedded C++](http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/) is more suited.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend the following projects

For general purpose library
[Poco Library](http://pocoproject.org/)  // does use exceptions 
[COID C++ object-serving networking library](https://code.google.com/p/coid/) // does use exception
[COID Documentation](http://coid.sourceforge.net/)

For UI and Framework (open source) 
[Qt](http://qt.digia.com/)
[WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)

Comment: As far as I can tell Poco uses exceptions as its primary error reporting mechanism...

Comment: I added it as a option as the only other source code that we integrate instead of boost because we're too scared to touch boost and its massive Template library.

Comment: Depending on your skills, you could avoid exception with Poco. Poco is a nice recomendation to use as general-use and cross-platform library. Easy to use and perfect complement to STL. For UI I think Chad is right too... QT and WxWidgets rocks